# How to vertically and horizontally center two images inside a div on a responsive page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate, normalize-css

I'm using Skeleton and Normalize css. I want to center two images side by side vertically and horizontally inside the div container. When the page becomes narrower, I want the 2nd image at the bottom of the first image as below

```
Normal width:
img1 img2

Narrow view:
img1
img2
```

Here is my code:

```
<div id="center">
    <div class="left">
        <img class="u-max-full-width" src="img1.jpg">
    </div>        
    <div class="right">
        <img class="u-max-full-width" src="img2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my css:

```css
#center {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}
#center > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.left {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

With this code, they are vertically centered in normal width but I cannot get the images aligned below each other in narrower view.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  
  display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

   <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
   
   <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">

</div>
```

**Edit:**
Sry didn't read properly..
These don't break up if the page gets narrow.

As François pointed out, add this to the css:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

**Another Edit:**
apparently IE has some problems with this. Make a wrapper around .container (container_wrapper) or something. Give it:

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
```

And make sure your html and body are set to 100% height

Comment: Now the two images do wrap one below the other like I wanted but two things are happening 1) it has centered all the content on the entire page instead of just the div with class 'container', 2) you used the two images that are 300x300 so they look fine but my two images are not of same height so they are not vertically aligned in the middle. They are vertically aligned at the bottom.

Comment: I was able align content to left but I cannot vertically align both the images to middle. Any idea?

Comment: If I run the code snippet how it is now, it's just how you asked. I don't know  why it's not working for you..

Comment: It works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE 8-Edge. In your code , try chaning height of one of the image.

Comment: If I add display:table to container and display:table-cell to images, IE displays properly but images are stacked in Chrome.

Comment: Allright found a solution for you:

Add a wrapper div around container. Give it:

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;

Oh and make sure your html and body is set to 100% height

Comment: Thanks Jip but didn't work. Added style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;height:100%;" to wrapper and html,body{height:100%} no change in IE, because of the column, now in broader view both the images are stacked in FF and Chrome.

Comment: May be because it is partially supported in IE 8-11 http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Figured it out, IE11 was running in Enterprise Browser profile even though the document mode was set to Edge. As soon as I changed browser profile to Dekstop, IE was able to recognize Flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

With the code of Jip van Kakerken, just add the property :

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

```css
.container {
  text-align:           center;
  
  display:     -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display:     -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display:     -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display:     -webkit-flex;
  display:     flex;
  
  justify-content:      center;

  -webkit-box-align:  center;
  -webkit-flex-align:  center;
  -ms-flex-align:   center;
  -webkit-align-items:  center;
  align-items:    center;
  flex-wrap:            wrap;

  height:               800px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

   <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
   
   <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">

</div>
```